# Lambda API timeout after function finishes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have a lambda function that is invoked using the JS API. The function finishes properly, we see the Lambda report in the logs.

```
END RequestId: c78a238e-fefd-11e8-935a-2526b5b5f5c1 
REPORT RequestId: c78a238e-fefd-11e8-935a-2526b5b5f5c1  Duration: 465968.78 ms   
Billed Duration: 466000 ms  Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 290 MB
```

Strangely, the API call returns an 'Unhandled' error.

```
   const params = {
       FunctionName: process.env.WORKER_LAMBDA,
       InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
       Payload: {}
   };

    this.lambda.invoke(params).promise()
        .then(result => this._handleResult(launchParams, result))
        .catch(error => this._handleResult(launchParams, error));
```

The result handler function logs the following:

```
Lambda result: { TimeoutError: Connection timed out after 990000.0000000001ms 
     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/opt/timeline/backend/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:83:34) 
     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30) 
     at emitNone (events.js:106:13) 
     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:208:7) 
     at TLSSocket.emitTimeout (_http_client.js:706:34) 
     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30) 
     at emitNone (events.js:106:13) 
     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7) 
     at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:410:8) 
     at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11) 
     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5) 
     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5) 
   message: 'Connection timed out after 990000.0000000001ms', 
   code: 'TimeoutError', 
   time: 2018-12-13T17:54:06.269Z, 
   region: 'us-east-1', 
   hostname: 'lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 
   retryable: true }
```

How come, the API returns an error, while the function finishes successfully, and AWS lambda know about it?

Thank you for any help!

Tamas

Comment: Are you invoking the callback parameter of your lambda function? This is a guaranteed way to stop the execution of the node process.

Comment: At least you don't have to mix .promise() with then/catch. Use try/catch block with .promise().

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630935/get-value-back-from-aws-lambda-invoke-synchronously/52633370#52633370

Comment: @Nikolay: Thanks, but whether I use promise.then().catch or try { await promise; } catch () is irrelevant to the original question. Either way, I get a timeout error from the API, while the lambda function actually finished properly.

Comment: @Tom: yes, the callback is called in the function. The strange thing is that Lambda even logs the billed duration (466s) used memory and everything. How come I still get a timeout error?

Comment: @tamas.mahr That seems like an issue you could bring up with AWS Support. Invoking the callback function should be the one-stop-shop for stopping execution of the container's node process.

One thing that does interest me is the following, do you actually get a response when you invoke it or is it just quiet until 990 seconds have passed and then throws a timeout error.

Comment: @Tom I don't get a response on the caller side, only the timeout. I will create a ticket on AWS, as you suggest.